# Android Load text from file as InputStream

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to load a `.pem` file which is a `self signed server certificate` in `android kotlin`. The file that performs this function is `CertUtils.kt` which is located in `/src/main/java/org/matrix/android/sdk/internal/network/ssl/CertUtils.kt`
However, in its implementation the file load process always fails because neither `file not found` nor `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: inStream == null`
I have tried several ways but still failed. Here are some of the methods I have used:

```
val caInput: InputStream = FileInputStream("server.pem")
val caInput: InputStream =CertUtil.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("server.pem")
val caInput: InputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/server.pem")
val caInput: InputStream= this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("server.pem")
val caInput: InputStream = FileInputStream("server.pem")
```

I've also tried saving the `server.pem` file in several places

```
/home/user/server.pem
/src/main/res/server.pem
/src/main/resources/server.pem
/src/main/java/org/matrix/android/sdk/internal/network/ssl/server.pem
```

but it's still wrong. Anybody can help ?

Comment: Is that code running on an Android device? If yes, then you should realize that those paths are not on an Android device.

Comment: Oh I see, i forgot about that. But shouldn't  getResourceAsStream can read the path ?

Comment: Should it do that when you are with your device in town?

Comment: `val caInput: InputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/server.pem")` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in `src/main/res/raw/`

```
val inputSteam = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.server);
```

(`resources` is available on the `Context` object i.e. in your Activity (`getResources()` for java))

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my question is incomplete. This is the problem, I can't access the context of the CertFile.kt file. This happens because there is no MainActivity in this project. Here's the project overview, I'm trying to build an element-vector app for android which can be accessed at `https://github.com/vector-im/element-android/`. The main project of this code is in the vector folder and the others are dependencies of the main project.
Now here the CertFile.kt file is in the matrix-android-sdk folder and the context cannot be accessed.

Comment: can you link straight to the file? I can't find it

Comment: in Android all code starts at a Context, so you need to find where this code is called from and either get the file there then pass the inputstream or pass the context, or pass the resources.